# Using OpenGL ES, Vulkan and DirectX in QEMU Aarch64 Release

Tags: qemu, opengl

I am using QEMU 7.0 Aarch64 (ARM64) on Android.  I am using Windows 11 ARM64, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with KVM.  I need 3D acceleration but I don't know how to open it.  It has Mali G76 MP4 GPU and supports OpenGL ES 3.2, Vulkan 1.1, DirectX 12 (FL11_1).

My specs:

Redmi Note 10S (Secret) 6/128

MediaTek Helio G95 (MT6785) SoC

Kernel: Linux 4.14.261Genom-R-J6idot-g4e0950a47157 aarch64